# Java StAX - error when parsing - Illegal character entity: expansion character code 0x19

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am reading/parsing an XML file with `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader`.
The file contains this piece of XML data as shown below.

```
<Row>
  <AccountName value="Paving 101" />
  <AccountNumber value="20205" />
  <AccountId value="15012" />
  <TimePeriod value="2019-08-20" />
  <CampaignName value="CMP Paving 101" />
  <CampaignId value="34283" />
  <AdGroupName value="residential paving" />
  <AdGroupId value="1001035" />
  <AdId value="790008" />
  <AdType value="Expanded text ad" />
  <DestinationUrl value="" />
  <BidMatchType value="Broad" />
  <Impressions value="1" />
  <Clicks value="1" />
  <Ctr value="100.00%" />
  <AverageCpc value="1.05" />
  <Spend value="1.05" />
  <AveragePosition value="2.00" />
  <SearchQuery value="concrete&#x19;driveway&#x19;repair&#x19;methods" />
</Row>
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error and I am not sure how to resolve it.

```
    Error in downloadXML: 
    com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x19
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [674,40]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.reportIllegalChar(StreamScanner.java:2448)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.validateChar(StreamScanner.java:2395)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.resolveSimpleEntity(StreamScanner.java:1218)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.parseAttrValue(BasicStreamReader.java:1929)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3063)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2961)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2837)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
```

The problem seems to be with this character `&#x19`.
Of course I can first read the file simply as a text file, and replace this bad character, and only then parse it with `XMLStreamReader` but:
1) that approach seems really clumsy to me;
2) it will be a bit difficult to do as the code is quite involved there,
so I am not sure if I want to change it just for this character.

Why is the XMLStreamReader unable to handle this character?
Is the XML invalid or the parser has a bug and does not handle it well?

Comment: The XML is invalid. That character entity is in a forbidden range. (The correct term is, the XML is "not well-formed". It's worse than invalid.)

Comment: The `&#x19;` character is not allowed in XML 1.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets). I'm not sure if it helps you, but the character is allowed in XML 1.1 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets).

Comment: @kumesana Which range is the forbidden range? Can you point me to some official/authoritative reference?

Comment: My XML file has this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` so it declares that it's 1.0. Right?

Comment: XML doesn't actually exist in any other version but 1.0 anyway. Nothing supports anything but that. The definitions of valid character ranges is in https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets and the following section tells that character reference also must be in that range: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-CharRef

Comment: XML 1.1 does exist. It is not very widely used, but it is a W3C recommendation since 2006.

Comment: @mzjn "not very widely used"... Probably because there is no tool providing support for it.

Comment: @kumesana The link you provided (NT-CharRef) gives this pattern: `'&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ';'`. But this pattern does not disallow `&#x19;`. Why do you say it's forbidden character then? What is this character actually? Is it the end of medium character (decimal 25)?

Comment: @kumesana Actually, I find your other link more useful. There we have `Char    ::=    #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`  According to this pattern `&#x19;` would be illegal indeed. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The pattern is not disallowed, but there is a well-form constraint when you want to use this pattern, and it says the pattern must produce a character in the valid range. Yes the character produced is end of medium

Comment: @kumesana Oh... OK, this `Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]` is the well-formedness constraint. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `&`, `<` and `>` (as well as `"` or `'` in attributes) are invalid in XML.

They're escaped using XML entities, in this case you want `&amp;` for `&`.

Your XML is invalid with every correct library ; (You need may be correct the producer of this XML content )

**Edit* from https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char

Allowed range for a entity reference :

```
Reference ::= EntityRef | CharRef 
EntityRef ::=       '&' Name ';'
CharRef   ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]    /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

Comment: yes but something like `&#x40;` would be perfectly fine, and be taken as another way to write the character `@`. The problem is that the hexa value 19 is in a forbidden range.

Comment: What does that mean "You need may be correct the producer of this XML content"? I get this XML file from an API? I guess it means I should notify the vendor of this API telling them their XML file is invalid?

Comment: For me the producer API contains a bug : try to validate the XML with an another XML validator : you will obtain an error concerning `&#x19`. As say @kumesana, it's a fordidden range

Comment: "I guess it means I should notify the vendor of this API telling them their XML file is invalid?" - yup